# what to type on a text editor find-and-replace to port python 2 prints to python3

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-2.x

I am trying to make [this](https://openassembler.wordpress.com/) open source project to run in python 3.

So far the only fix is to replace `print whatever` to `print(whatever)`

Is there any way to tell the find and replace tool of pycharm to do this?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a text editor for this. Use `2to3` instead. It comes with Python.